# DataTable Fixed Header at page bottom (on first page load)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, fixed-header-tables

I have a [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) with [FixedHeader](https://datatables.net/reference/option/fixedHeader) option that has the following initialization populated in my `$(document).ready` function. Both the headerOffset values that are jquery looked-up and hard-coded at 40 have been attempted, with the same results.

```
    "fixedHeader": {
        // "headerOffset": $("#top-navbar").outerHeight()
        "headerOffset": 40
    },
```

The DataTable is populated from an ajax call and has a series of my own `render:` functions on half of the `columnDefs` but I don't think that's related.

I'm not sure why, but the first time the page is loaded, the fixedHeader doesn't follow the top of the screen - but is sitting at the very bottom of the page below the table. When I click refresh - the header works just fine.

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and in the absence of a satisfactory solution, my current workaround is to trigger a window resize event that will make the `Datatable` make rendering recalculations:

```
table.DataTable({

  // ...

  drawCallback: function() {
    $(window).resize();
  }

});
```